# Read_excel rounds decimal values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, decimal

When using read_excel as follows, values are being rounded to either integer or a decimal less

```
import pandas as pd
p=pd.read_excel('aa.xlsx', sheet_name=1) 
print(p.iloc[:,5])
```

So the 5th column prints

306268

306268

59771.2

148397

45618.3

40137.3

instead of initial values

[image]

The excel cells format is currency

Any ideas how to get those initial values properly?

Comment: Did you try passing dtypes

Comment: I ran your snippet with an example xlsx file and was not able to reproduce your error, *i.e.* 45618.35 indeed returned 45618.35.

Comment: What is the result of `p.iloc[0,5] == 306267.89`?